# How to add my own validation code to a MooTools lightface form

Tags: javascript, forms, mootools, validation

I have created a simple javascript function to validate a form which was created using mootools to work in a facebook app:

Facebook comepetition app [Click here](http://www.webninjas.ie/apps/facebook/sns-contest-danny/contest/index/2)

the orginal validation was done using HTML5 but as this does not work in all browsers I had to try and come up with something that would! So i created a simple javascript function and I know it works but i am having trouble getting it to work with the mootools lightface as i had the validation working onClick of the submit button but with the lightface plugin i dont get the option to do this as the submit button is defined independantly of the form if that makes sense?

I cant figure out how to upload the code here but if you go to the link and select "Chuckie" as the answer you will see the form displayed and can view the frame source from there!

here is my validation code:

```
function validate(form) {
    var fail = false;
    var name = document.getElementById("full_name");

    if (name.value.length == 0) {
      document.getElementById("okName").className = "fail";
      fail = true;
    }else{
      document.getElementById("okName").className = "success";
    }



    var email = document.getElementById("email");
    var emailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;

    if (email.value.length == 0 || !emailPattern.test(email.value)) {
      document.getElementById("okEmail").className = "fail";
        fail = true;
    }else{
      document.getElementById("okEmail").className = "success";
    }



    var phone = document.getElementById("phone");
    var phonePattern = /^\+?[0-9]{0,15}$/ ;

    if (phone.value.length == 0 || !phonePattern.test(phone.value)) {
      document.getElementById("okPhone").className = "fail";
        fail = true;
    }else{
      document.getElementById("okPhone").className = "success";
    }

    if ( fail ) {
        alert( "You didn't fill out all inputs" );
    } else {
        alert( "Everything OK" );
    }
}//End of validation function
```

all i basically want is to pass this method to the mootools submit button if possible?

Answer (score 0):

you really ought to give Form.Validator a spin (from mootools-more).

come with a bunch of pre-made validators as well as with the ability to define validators yourself.

http://mootools.net/docs/more/Forms/Form.Validator

also, if you are using mootools, you probably want to stay within the api.

- `document.getElementById()` -> `document.id()`
- `element.value` -> `element.get('value')`
- `element.addClass('validation-failed')`
- `element.toggleClass('validation-failed')`
- `element.hasClass('validation-failed')`
- `element.property = value` -> `element.set('property', value);`

if this function is meant to run on a submit event, you probably want to change it so it's bound to the form as context (`this`) with argument being the `event` that you can stop.

```
function validate(event) {
    var fail = false;

    // logic.


    if (fail) {
        event && event.stop && event.stop();
        return false;
    }
    this.submit();
}

document.id('someform').addEvent('submit', validate);
```